# Как выполнить несколько программных переходов между ViewController подряд?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Нужно сделать 2 действия подряд, то есть например закрыть модальное окно и вернуться в прошлый контроллер из которого был пуш или вернуться и перейти на новый.
Если я пишу:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
```

То в итоге получаю ошибку.

Comment: тут не понятно, зачем переходить в предыдущий контроллер, чтоб перейти в какой либо новый?

ну и по коду, вы уже сделали popViewControllerAnimated и хотите сделать pushViewController в этом же методе.

Comment: Если я например зашёл в ячейку №1, а после мне необходимо программно перейти в ячейку №2, то не буду же я переходить из ячейки №1. Надо сначало вернуться назад, а после зайти в ячейку №2. Вот зачем.

Comment: хм.. а если после первой нужно перейти в третью?

Comment: если категорически во вторую, то можно в viewDidAppear переходить в ячейку +1 от выбранной до этого

Answer (score 2):

## исправленно

```
UITestViewController * testViewController = [[UITestViewController alloc] init];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ { [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES]; }];
```

upd: пока автор молчит, ответ оставлю таким

Comment: Не, вы меня не правильно поняли, контроллер на который будет осуществлён переход уже известен, надо просто сделать чтобы выходило из того в котором сейчас и заходило в этот известный.

Comment: >надо просто сделать чтобы выходило из того в котором сейчас и заходило в этот известный.
т.е. по какому-то событию. мы тогда делаем выход:  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

и через делегата передаем в viewDidAppear(или в какой вам удобно) в предыдущем, что нам нужно перейти в "этот известный"

но я считаю это не нормально, или я так и не понял задачу.. ))

p.s. до мака я так и не добрался пока

Comment: >контроллер на который будет осуществлён переход уже известен, надо просто сделать чтобы выходило из того в котором сейчас и заходило в этот известный.

т.е. вы просто хотите убить тот в котором сейчас и перейти в новый?

если так, то это добавить в событие на контроллере после ячейки

UITestViewController * testViewController = [[UITestViewController alloc] init];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
}];

Comment: если через блок помогло, то скажите, я тогда ответ исправлю

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `setViewControllers:animated:` у `UINavigationController:`

```
[self.navigaitonController setViewControllers:[[self.navigationController.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@", self]] arrayByAddingObject:newViewController] animated:YES];
```

Последний `UIViewController` в массиве - тот, что будет на экране. 
Выфильтровываем оттуда текущий `UIViewController` с помощью `[self.navigationController.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@", self]` и добавляем последним новый экран `arrayByAddingObject:newViewController]`